# does there exist something like yahoo answers that I can host myself?

Tags: web-applications

I'm looking to make a alternative to wiki-type documentation for a program I use (http://reaper.fm). the wiki isn't maintained well and I think a database of "how do i *_* in reaper?" would be much more effective. even stackoverflow itself is nearly what I'd be looking for. open source would be nice because I'm just doing this to help myself and others learn how to use reaper, but if it's not then maybe I could get a few enthusiasts to pitch in.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should direct your users to use one of the many [StackExchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for any questions related to your application. The ethos of the StackExchange family is that there doesn't need to be a separate forums etc. for each technology out there.

Comment: -1 Maybe they could ask on Superuser, but Reaper is definitely off-topic on SO.

Comment: Applogies, then maybe a better answer would be, @jeffery have a look at the [stack exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) and see which best fits your user base.

Comment: If you edit your answer to include that I would convert to an upvote.

Comment: I looked at all the sites on SO and didn't find any that fit the topic. If there was a general topic like "audio recording" then the chances would go down to find app-specific help as there are many many audio recording applications out there, and reaper lesser known. I would probably decide against making a custom site if there was a music production related SO topic though. I'm sure I could rally some knowledgable users to use SO for reaper (and audio recording) related help.

Comment: Well that was my two penny's worth, but as @cdhowie said So it probably not the best place to ask questions regarding how to use software. Not sure I can help with anything beyond what I have already suggested, which is obviously not appropriate for you circumstances.